# Failed to read or create install properties file.ndroid Emulator sdk-pa

Tags: android, linux, terminal, kivy, buildozer

I am using buildozer to make Android-App from python-kivy file. After running the code:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

I got the error:

```
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.ndroid Emulator sdk-pa
# Command failed: /home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
```

I have no idea what this warning means and what should I do.
There are some helps on "Androis-studio", but I am on python.

Any help is very appreciated

the whole terminal result is:

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.4 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/kouhi/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master dd69749 [origin/master] Merge pull request #1955 from kivy/release-2019.08.09
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 17c
# Android NDK found at /home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
# Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary
# Run '/home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools'
# Cwd /home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.ndroid Emulator sdk-pa
# Command failed: /home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     UPSTART_SESSION = 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1415'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     GTK2_MODULES = 'overlay-scrollbar'
#     VTE_VERSION = '4205'
#     LC_NAME = 'fa_IR'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     HOME = '/home/kouhi'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'fa_IR'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     PWD = '/home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'fa_IR'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SESSIONTYPE = 'gnome-session'
#     WINDOWID = '10485947'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     INSTANCE = ''
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'appmenu-qt5'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-vQEhPLNjUq'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_PID = ''
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_PAPER = 'fa_IR'
#     LOGNAME = 'kouhi'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     LC_TIME = 'fa_IR'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON = '1'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/kouhi/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     USER = 'kouhi'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/kouhi'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'fa_IR'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL = ''
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     JOB = 'dbus'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/home/kouhi/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/kouhi-PC:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1691,unix/kouhi-PC:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1691'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'fa_IR'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     PATH = '/home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/kouhi/bin:/home/kouhi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'fa_IR'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'fa_IR'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Never seen this before, please post the full buildozer output.

Comment: @inclement  great thanks for your consideration. The output is added to the body of the question.

Comment: Looks like something went wrong during the sdkmanager step, but unclear what or why. Could maybe be something like running out of disk space?

Comment: Try navigating to `home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk` and running `/home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools`

Comment: @inclement  thanks for your consideration. I increase the free space from 15 GB to around 30GB.  So now the error changed to :   Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools: archive is not a ZIP archive.
# Command failed: /home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools

Comment: @inclement   I dont understand your meaning from "running ...".  What should I write in the terminal?   I am so sorry if my question is very basic. Unfortunately, I do not understand what to do.

Comment: Delete `~/.buildozer` and run buildozer again, then post the full log.

Comment: @inclement great thanks. somehow it solved, but the new error is "Aidl not found, please install it."    So, I tried to download it: ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.0"      but still not work with the error "Aidl not found, please install it." .  Also, I found the "notice.txt" file in the tools folder which mentiond the version 26.0.0.  So I download ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.0" as well. Still, have the same problem!!

Comment: @inclement  Also I have to mention that after downloading "build-tools;29.0.0" or "build-tools;26.0.0" no "y-n" question was asked at the terminal.  (at this website it mentioned that I will see y-n question to accept the license. https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)